# How to use the result of Enum.GetValues() method?

Tags: c#

I'm new in c#.
I want to know the how to convert the result of the method Enum.GetValues() into the array of string?
This is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnumList)))
                Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
    public enum MyEnumList
    {
        egg, apple, orange, potato
    }
}
```

Now I don't want to have foreach on the result. I want to store the result as an string[] variable.
Thank you.

Comment: [Enum.GetNames Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getnames?view=net-5.0) - _"Retrieves an array of the names of the constants in a specified enumeration."_

Comment: `I don't want to have foreach on the result` what *do* you want? Both `GetValues` and `GetNames` return arrays

Comment: Ah, wait. Do you want the _numerical_ values as `string[]`? If so: _why??_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you want an array of names**, you can just use [`Enum.GetNames` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getnames?view=net-5.0)

> Retrieves an array of the names of the constants in a specified enumeration.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnumList));
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(",", names));
    }
}
public enum MyEnumList
{
    egg, apple, orange, potato
}
```

[output](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZbJ2kX):

> [egg,apple,orange,potato]

---

**If you want a `string[]` of the numeric values**:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] enumAsStrings = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnumList)) // strongly typed values
                                     .Cast<int>() // Get the _numeric_ values
                                     .Select(x => x.ToString()) // conv. to string
                                     .ToArray(); // give me an array
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}]",string.Join(",", enumAsStrings));
    }
}
public enum MyEnumList
{
    egg, apple, orange, potato
}
```

[output](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1xJf5W):

> [0,1,2,3]

Comment: I want to have something like string[] names that it has a list of Names. how to find it?

Comment: @HosseinSedghian Enum.GetNames: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6zRuHm I cannot possibly put it any more simple and explicit. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want something like that:

```
    var enums = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnumList)).Cast<MyEnumList>().Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToArray();
```